# Clean redirect from JS using Rails Turbolinks (with Url params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks

Starting Rails web url: /analytics?param1=a&param2=b

If the user changes calendar dates it triggers a JS function with the new selected dates (start_date and end_date).
Then I have to pass them to the controller together with previous params1 and params2 and reload the page.

*New web URL:* /analytics?param1=a&param2=b&start_date=YYYY&end_date=YYYY

Note: param1 and param2 could be missing and optional.

I want to use Turbolinks but I am wondering which is the cleanest way to do this.

```
  $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        let startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let endDate   = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        Turbolinks.visit(....)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your required level of browser support, you could do this with `URLSearchParams`:

```js
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  const startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  const endDate   = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  params.set('start_date', startDate)
  params.set('end_date', endDate)

  Turbolinks.visit(window.location.pathname + '?' + params.toString())
});
```

If you don't want to stay on the same path as you currently are (I understood this from your question, so I assume you do want to stay), then you need to change `window.location.pathname` to whatever is the target path.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams for documentation.